# Llamar una función php en un botón en otra pagina php

Tags: php, html

Estoy realizando una tarea con mi grupo para la universidad, estamos trabajando con `php`, `html`, `js` y `postgres`, y surgió esta duda, tengo esta función en un archivo `php`, bajo el nombre de **funciones.php** mediante la cual quiero actualizar los datos en la base de datos que tenemos.

```
function Mod_Est ($ci, $nombre, $apellidop, $apellidom, $fec_nac, $telefono, $correo){
    $query1 = "UPDATE persona SET nombre=$nombre, apellidop=$apellidop, apellidom=$apellidom, fechanaci=$fec_nac, WHERE ci= $ci";
    $query2 = "UPDATE comunicación SET teléfono=$telefono, correo=$correo WHERE persona_ci=$ci";
    $res1 = pg_query($query1);
    $res2 = pg_query($query2);
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es poder llamar a esta función desde un botón ubicado en otra pagina `php`, la cual ya tiene puesto el respectivo `include` llamando a este archivo `php`.

```
<div Class="wrapper" id="editardatos" class="container-fluid" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul class="list-group row">
                <li class="list-group-item">NOMBRE</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">APELLIDO PATERNO</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">APELLIDO MATERNO</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">FECHA NACIMIENTO</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">TELEFONO</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">CORREO ELECTRONICO</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <form action method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="nombre">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="apellidop">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="apellidom">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="fec_nac">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="telefono">
                <input type="text" class="list-group-item" id="correo">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="on">ENVIAR</button>
</div>
```

¿Cómo podría hacer que el `submit` me permita llamar a la función para poder usarla, y si no es posible con el `submit` de que otra forma podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo de manera sencilla es en la cual envias todos los input dentro del formulario.

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="nombre" id="nombre">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="apellidop" id="apellidop">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="apellidom" id="apellidom">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="fec_nac" id="fec_nac">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="telefono" id="telefono">
<input type="text" class="list-group-item" name="correo" id="correo">
</form>
```

Ahora en el archivo de funciones.php debes de recibirlos de la siguiente manera:

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidop = $_POST["apellidop"];
```

Y así sucesivamente para que después a tu función le pases los parámetros recibidos.

Comment: Hola, he seguido la explicacion que me diste y al principio no me aceptaba las variables que habia declarado e incluso hizo que dejara de funcionar la otra funcion que tenia, ya hice cambios y ya manda los valores y veo que los recibe, pero pareciera que no entran a la funcion para ejecutar las consultas ¿alguna idea del por que?

Comment: Puede ser por varias cosas una de ella es que solo envías los datos más no haces que realice la función en si para ello deberías de llamar a tu función Mod_Est($aqui_todos_los_parametros_que_recibes), o mejor aún, elimina la parte de la función y deja solo el contenido que tienes ($query1, $query2) y así debería de hacerlo.

Comment: Te ayudaría con el código pero ando en el teléfono Broder. Si gustas dame unos 15 minutos (pero inténtalo y sino me dices y te ayudo)

Comment: Gracias, resulto que el problema estaba en una coma de la consulta, arreglado eso todo funciono bien

Answer (score 0):

prueba metiendo un action en el form.
`<form action action=funciones.php method="POST">`

en vez de funciones.php pon el nombre del archivo el cual deseas llamar con su respectivo tipo `.php` en este caso